# Entities vs Abstract Database Relationship

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

I know it is a redundant question for all of us in the internet. But i want to have a simple and clear explanation about defining a database relationship.

> 1. Should database relationship depends on actions? (A User can create Post, A user can like a Post, etc.)
> 2. Should database relationship depends on the related entities. (An event has many post, Every event is associated with many post and likes. A user has a post in an event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a redundant question. Data models in general, and the entity-relationship model in particular, are generally poorly understood, and most online tutorials, blog articles and product documentation contain half-truths at best.

Relationships are used to record any association a person or system needs to keep track of. The focus here is *knowledge*, databases are used to record, manipulate and derive *information* of interest to a person or system. A relationship is nothing more than a fact which involves one or more entities.

Does your system need to remember which users are allowed to create posts or like posts, or which users actually did those things (and what posts they did them to)? Does it need to know which posts belong to which events, which user has which post in which event? All of those are valid examples.

Basically, any sentence with placeholders is a predicate, e.g. *User [user_id] liked post [post_id]*. When you replace the placeholders with values, you get an individual relationship, also called a proposition or a fact. It's common to use "relationship" to also mean a relationship set, i.e. any number of individual relationships with the same predicate statement, and this is what's represented by tables in databases.

Note that relationships are NOT represented by foreign key constraints in databases. That's a common misconception often propagated online, even by popular DBMS vendors who should know better.